# Return after for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am writing a function that takes a list and checks if it contains 12. I don't understand why the function does not work if I have two return statements like this.

```
def check_12(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i == 12:
            return True
        else:
            return False

test = [1,2,3,12]
print(check_12(test))
```

It should return True, but returns False instead.

Comment: In the first iteration of the loop, where i = 1, your if condition `i == 12` is False, hence, we defer to the else condition, which is to return False.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning too early and, thus, only checking if the first element is `12`:

```
def check_12(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i == 12:
            return True
    return False
```

Note that you only know **after** the loop has finished that the searched element is not in there. There is a util (`any`) for this exact pattern:

```
def check_12(lst):
    return any(i == 12 for i in lst)
```

Of course, in this special case, there is an even faster way to achieve this:

```
def check_12(lst):
    return 12 in lst
```

Comment: That is a great explanation! But what about, as we iterate through each item in a list, and there is no item equals 12, why can't we return False within an Else statement within the for loop?

Comment: The `return` ends the function right then and there. You would always return from the first iteration and never finish the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return False once you've iterated through the whole list, not during the first iteration (so remove "else" statement and move it one tab to the left).

```py
def check_12(lst):
    for i in lst:
        if i == 12:
            return True
    return False

test = [1,2,3,12]
print(check_12(test))
```